# Create a font with colored glyphs (emojis)

Tags: colors, fonts, emoji

how can I create my own font with colored glyphs (emojis).

I dont care which programming language (but I would prefer python if possible) and which file format the glyphs need. I just want to create a font which constains colored emojis .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an app like [FontCreator](https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator).

If you have some existing emoji artwork and want some python tools to generate a font using that artwork, then check out the [nanoemoji](https://github.com/googlefonts/nanoemoji) module developed by the Google Fonts team.

Comment: thank you, I will try it :)

but I also want to code it by myself, how can I do this?

Comment: "Code it" is vague: Do you want to write a font-authoring tool from scratch? Do you want to take some existing color emoji artwork and some existing command-line tools to generate a font? Something in between? I'll update the answer with a different suggestion; if that doesn't hit the mark, then clarify the question.

Comment: the glyph artworks I want to create by my self with inkscape or other program. probbaly I wont use the same tool all the time beacuse there are really many emojis and probably I will find a better one by time... with these glyphs I want to create a colored font. I will look if the module you mentioned is what I search for 

Comment: unfortunately I couldnt find a good documentation.
can u post a link to a documentation or give me a minimal expample how to create a font and adding the glyph? 